# Opening VS Code settings window from extension with specific search query

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VS Code extension where I want to open the settings window programmatically from my extension. I want the window to already have the search filled out to only show the settings my extension provides, and also a way to select workspace settings vs user settings when opening the window. I know how to run vscode commands from my extension, but I cannot figure out which commands open that window.

Answer (score 16):

You can now pass an argument to the search, e.g.

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand( 'workbench.action.openSettings', 'editor.formatOnSaveTimeout' );
```

or

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand( 'workbench.action.openSettings', '<your extension>' );
```

Comment: the parameter is not in effect any more

Comment: It works fine for me in 1.39.2 and 1.40.0-insider. What makes you think it's been removed?

Answer (score 2):

You can open the Settings page using:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.openSettings');
```

And to focus on the search input:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand('settings.action.search');
```

However, I do not believe it's possible to specify a search value, filter by an extension, or choose the scope (user or workspace). You may open a feature request in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode).

Comment: FYI it's possible now  to open the workspace settings by doing `commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.openWorkspaceSettings', 'telemetry');`

Answer (score 2):

Just to be complete, the other answers will open the Settings UI with the string as the query.

But what if you want to open `settings.json` instead, perhaps because the setting is an object that must be edited in `settings.json` and not the UI?

As of vscode v1.81 there is a new way to do that (see [revealSetting and focusSearch, Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_81.md#revealsetting-and-focussearch-added-to-iopensettingsactionoptions):

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.openSettingsJson', { revealSetting: { key: 'decorateFiles.filePaths', edit: true }});
```

It uses `openSettingsJson` to open the actual JSON file not the Settings UI.  The `edit` command is optional, with it set to true the setting will be focused and the cursor will be inside on a new line ready to edit, like:

```json
decorateFiles.filePaths: {
  |                    // cursor at the pipe
  "out/**": "#f00",
  ".ts": "#00f"
}
```

If there is no `edit` or it is `false` the setting is focussed but the cursor is not inside the setting ready for editing.

The object `{ revealSetting: { key, edit}}` does not work in the `workbench.action.openSettings` command (the one that opens the Settings UI).