# Opening the VSC settings window from code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a Visual Studio Code extension, where some settings are required for it to work properly. Right now, in case the user has forgotten something, I'm showing a warning message indicating this, and telling them to fix this `property` in the settings. I would, however, like to add a `button` that opens the `settings` page of that `property`.

However, after looking around for over an hour, I can't seem to find any support for this in the Api, or anyone else asking this question (which I find a bit weird?). If it really doesn't exist, I'd still expect at least 1 other person asking this somewhere, but as far as I can see there's absolutely nothing.

Is it possible to open the settings window (preferably even filtering them down to only my extension's properties/the one property that has to be filled in) from code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584266/opening-vs-code-settings-window-from-extension-with-specific-search-query/76791874#76791874 for more additional info on opening the settings.json file focused to a particular setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out myself after digging through the `keybinds` window. You can use the following to open the `settings`:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.openSettings2");
```

I did not, however, find how to pass a search query into it to open a specific place in the settings.

EDIT: You can use `openSettings` & add the search query as an extra argument to `executeCommand`. For example - if your property is defined as `my.extension.property` in `package.json`, you can use this:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.openSettings", "my.extension.property");
```